# Storing questions to an array of data

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, comments

I've been trying to figure out how to add comments to an array of data in my local db. The idea I'm working on now is to add the array of comments to the array of data so it's easy to know which comment is for which set of data. When I try to do so using the following code, it won't work:

(This is in the userschema where I define the array that will hold the data)

```
test1: { type: array, required: false }
```

(Next I try to add the comment array with push but it won't work, I'm using test 0 as an example normally it will depend on what test you'd like to add your comments to. Test1 consists in turn of more arrays with the data in question to which I want to add the comments. Which is why I use user.test1[0])

```
user.test1[0].push(newComment);
```

(That does not work while the following does using splice)

```
user.test1.splice(1, 0, newComment)
```

For some reason it seems like a can't access the user.test1[0] but I have no idea why? Or should I use another technique when it comes to adding comments to a test?

---

```
app.updateTest1 = function(newComment1, newComment2, index) {
          app.errorMsg = false; // Clear any error message
          app.disabled = true; // Lock form while processing
          // Check if username submitted is valid
          var userObject = {}; // Create the user object to pass to function
          userObject._id = app.currentUser; // Pass current user _id in order to edit

          userObject.test1 = [$scope.newComment1, $scope.newComment2];

          User.editUser(userObject).then(function(data) {

          });
        };


    userFactory.editUser = function(id) {
        return $http.put('/api/edit', id);
    };


   router.put('/edit', function(req, res) {
        var editUser = req.body._id; // Assign _id from user to be editted to a variable
        if (req.body.name) var newName = req.body.name; // Check if a change to name was requested
        if (req.body.username) var newUsername = req.body.username; // Check if a change to username was requested
        if (req.body.email) var newEmail = req.body.email; // Check if a change to e-mail was requested
        if (req.body.permission) var newPermission = req.body.permission; // Check if a change to permission was requested

        if (req.body.test1) {
          var newTest1 = req.body.test1;
        }
        if (req.body.test2) {
          var firstTest2 = req.body.test2;
          var newTest2 = firstTest2.split(" ");
        }
        if (req.body.test3) {
          var firstTest3 = req.body.test3;
          var newTest3 = firstTest3.split(" ");
        }
        if (req.body.test4) {
          var firstTest4 = req.body.test4;
          var newTest4 = firstTest4.split(" ");
        }
        if (req.body.test5) {
          var firstTest5 = req.body.test5;
          var newTest5 = firstTest5.split(" ");
        }

        // Look for logged in user in database to check if have appropriate access
        User.findOne({ username: req.decoded.username }, function(err, mainUser) {
            if (err) {
                // Create an e-mail object that contains the error. Set to automatically send it to myself for troubleshooting.
                var email = {
                    from: 'MEAN Stack Staff, cruiserweights@zoho.com',
                    to: 'gugui3z24@gmail.com',
                    subject: 'Error Logged',
                    text: 'The following error has been reported in the MEAN Stack Application: ' + err,
                    html: 'The following error has been reported in the MEAN Stack Application:<br><br>' + err
                };
                // Function to send e-mail to myself
                client.sendMail(email, function(err, info) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err); // If error with sending e-mail, log to console/terminal
                    } else {
                        console.log(info); // Log success message to console if sent
                        console.log(user.email); // Display e-mail that it was sent to
                    }
                });
                res.json({ success: false, message: 'Something went wrong. This error has been logged and will be addressed by our staff. We apologize for this inconvenience!' });
            } else {
                // Check if logged in user is found in database
                if (!mainUser) {
                    res.json({ success: false, message: "no user found" }); // Return error
                } else {
                    // Check if a change to name was requested
                    if (newName) {
                        // Check if person making changes has appropriate access
                        if (mainUser.permission === 'admin' || mainUser.permission === 'moderator') {
                            // Look for user in database
                            User.findOne({ _id: editUser }, function(err, user) {
                                if (err) {
                                    // Create an e-mail object that contains the error. Set to automatically send it to myself for troubleshooting.
                                    var email = {
                                        from: 'MEAN Stack Staff, cruiserweights@zoho.com',
                                        to: 'gugui3z24@gmail.com',
                                        subject: 'Error Logged',
                                        text: 'The following error has been reported in the MEAN Stack Application: ' + err,
                                        html: 'The following error has been reported in the MEAN Stack Application:<br><br>' + err
                                    };
                                    // Function to send e-mail to myself
                                    client.sendMail(email, function(err, info) {
                                        if (err) {
                                            console.log(err); // If error with sending e-mail, log to console/terminal
                                        } else {
                                            console.log(info); // Log success message to console if sent
                                            console.log(user.email); // Display e-mail that it was sent to
                                        }
                                    });
                                    res.json({ success: false, message: 'Something went wrong. This error has been logged and will be addressed by our staff. We apologize for this inconvenience!' });
                                } else {
                                    // Check if user is in database
                                    if (!user) {
                                        res.json({ success: false, message: 'No user found' }); // Return error
                                    } else {
                                        user.name = newName; // Assign new name to user in database
                                        // Save changes
                                        user.save(function(err) {
                                            if (err) {
                                                console.log(err); // Log any errors to the console
                                            } else {
                                                res.json({ success: true, message: 'Name has been updated!' }); // Return success message
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            res.json({ success: false, message: 'Insufficient Permissions' }); // Return error
                        }
                    }


                    if (newTest1) {
                      // Check if person making changes has appropriate access
                      if (mainUser.permission === 'admin') {
                          // Look for user in database
                          User.findOne({ _id: editUser }, function(err, user) {
                              if (err) {
                                  res.json({ success: false, message: 'Something went wrong. This error has been logged and will be addressed by our staff. We apologize for this inconvenience!' });
                              } else {
                                  // Check if user is in database
                                  if (!user) {
                                      res.json({ success: false, message: 'No user found' }); // Return error
                                  } else {

-> (this is where i think the problem is) if (Array.isArray(newTest1)) {
                                          var index = newTest1[2];
   -> this doesn't work                      user.test1[0].push(newTest1);
                                              //user.test1.splice(index, 0, newTest1)
                                        } else {
                                          var testet1 = newTest1.split(" ");
                                          user.test1.push(testet1); // Assign new name to user in database
                                        }



                                          // Save changes
                                          user.save(function(err) {
                                              if (err) {
                                                  console.log(err); // Log any errors to the console
                                              } else {
                                                  res.json({ success: true, message: 'Name has been updated!' }); // Return success message
                                              }
                                          });
                                  }
                              }
                          });
                      } else {
                          res.json({ success: false, message: 'Insufficient Permissions' }); // Return error
                      }
                    }
```

Comment: Try `user.test1.push` and not `user.test1[0].push`. With `test1[0]` you are referencing a value and not the array itself.

`test1.splice(0, 1, 'newComment')` should also work

Comment: Test1 consists in turn of more arrays with the data in question to which I want to add the comments. Which is why I use user.test1[0]

Comment: Then you need to make test1[0] an array first. `test1[0]=[]` and then make `user.test1[0].push(1)`

Comment: I'm quite sure I pushed in the test resaults as an array. How come I need to make them into an array again?

Comment: Can't say without looking through full code block. Maybe there is a bug hidden somewhere

Comment: Could you possibly take a quick look if you have time?

Comment: Sure. Is it too big to post here?

Comment: No I think it would be possible to post here. I'm at work currently, could I send it later tonight?

Comment: No problem. Just keep in mind I live in UTC + 03.00 time zone

Comment: Hey, I just added the code please have a look. I can't get it to work.

Comment: Hello. Looking through your code I found nothing but all the same I told you earlier. `user.test1[0].push` is not working because it's refering an undefined value in the empty array. If you try to use `user.test1[0].splice` it won't work either. So the only solution I see is to get rid of `[0]` completely. If you make it  `user.test1.push(newTest1)` or `user.test1.splice(1,0, newTest1)` it should work as intended. I've created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/119wdva8/) where you can test this out

Comment: That's what confuses me. I've since before added arrays to the user.test1 which I can see in the database so I know for a fact it's not empty. Could it be that you don't refere to a array within an array like this: user.test1[0]?

Comment: Yes those last ones work but they add the value to the wrong array. I want the added array to be within the teat1 so that they are connected since those comments are for that test. Is there any other way of connecting them that you would recommend? Really appreciate your help!

Comment: So you want to make `user.test[0]` something like this `[ [1,2,3][4,5,6] ]` ?

Comment: Either like that or [ [1, 2, 3, [1, 2, 3]]]

Comment: Then I can't get why `user.test1.push` is adding the value to the wrong way. It will add an array with comments as the last element of the parent array. Join [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/119wdva8/1/#&togetherjs=VVIC3wcLAt)

Comment: As test1 is now it looks like this:[ [], [], [], [] ] with a lot of arrays with tear values. Sorry but I need to put the comment in the same array as the test not in just in test1 like this:[ [1, 2, [comments], [], [], [] ]

Comment: can you join [JSFiddle Collaboration](https://jsfiddle.net/119wdva8/1/#&togetherjs=VVIC3wcLAt) so we  could fasten the process of chatting and looking through the code? =)

Comment: I'm unfortunately at work again but would love to do so in about 7 h when I get home. Do you think you'll be online then?

Comment: Will be home online in 8 hours from now

Comment: Perfect, I'll be in touch then.

Comment: I'll be a bit late they wanted me to work over, can we maybe push it one hour? Really appreciate all of this.

Comment: No problem. I'll just open JS Fiddle and will be online awaiting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure `user.test1[0]` value exists before manipulating it. So if your `user.test1`

```js
var user = {};
user.test = [];
var arrayToPush = [1,2,3];

try {
 user.test[0].push(arrayToPush)
 } catch (err) {
  document.getElementById('out').innerHTML += err
 }
 
 var user2 ={}
 user2.test=[];
 
 try {
 user2.test.push(arrayToPush)
  user2.test.push(arrayToPush)
 } catch (err) {
  document.getElementById('out2').innerHTML += err
 }
 document.getElementById('out2').innerHTML += user2.test[0]
```

```html
<div id="out"></div>
<br>
<div id="out2"></div>
```

array has no values at all you can't push to it anything.